# Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'Action' when upgrading @ngrx/Store

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have the `@ngrx/store` package in my angular (4.x) app, and am upgrading from v**2.2.2** -> v**4.0.0**. I can see that the migration notes say:

> The payload property has been removed from the Action interface.

However, the example they give seems completely counter intuitive (in my view...).

I have a reducer function which looks like this:

```
export function titleReducer(state = { company: 'MyCo', site: 'London' }, action: Action): ITitle {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_TITLE':
            return {
                company: action.payload.company,
                site: action.payload.site,
                department: action.payload.department,
                line: action.payload.line
            }
        case 'RESET':
            return {
                company: 'MyCo',
                site: 'London'
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Which as expected now throws typescript error:

> [ts] Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'Action'

But I have no idea from the migration guide what this should be changed too. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show import of Action class?

Comment: @JaroslawK. `import { ActionReducer, Action } from '@ngrx/store';`

Comment: Ok, could you show how you called Action with payload? in effect or other way

Comment: @JaroslawK. I am not quite sure what you mean, the above is my reducer function, which I then provide to my app module and then `.select('title')` in my components. I don't directl call Action anywhere

Comment: I'm talking about, where you dispatch Action ( .dispatch(new Action() or Effect)

Comment: @JaroslawK. Oh I see - like this: `this.store.dispatch({ type: 'SET_TITLE', payload: { department: this.dep } })`

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Read it from [**here**](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/README.md). `ngrx-store 4.0` will no longer support payload property

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can create your own action type that has a `payload` defined, check [the example app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/48a2381c212d5dd3fa2b9435776c1aaa60734235/example-app/app/books/actions/collection.ts#L17) for reference:

```
class AddBookAction implements Action {
    readonly type = ADD_BOOK;

    constructor(public payload: Book) {}
}
```

Then use that type in [the reducer](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/48a2381c212d5dd3fa2b9435776c1aaa60734235/example-app/app/books/reducers/collection.ts#L15):

```
function reducer(state = initialState, action: AddBookAction): State
```

Action could be dispatched like [this](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/48a2381c212d5dd3fa2b9435776c1aaa60734235/example-app/app/books/containers/selected-book-page.ts#L33):

```
this.store.dispatch(new AddBookAction(book));
```

Note also that the example app [combines](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/48a2381c212d5dd3fa2b9435776c1aaa60734235/example-app/app/books/actions/collection.ts#L75) all the action types that a reducer can take into a single union type:

```
export type Actions =
    | AddBookAction
    | AddBookSuccessAction

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: Actions): State
```

Comment: After comparing elvirdolic solution on https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/31 and other answers on SO this is the best approach. Create action classes, create custom action type that implements Action and adds `payload` property and then dispatch action classes. Clean and more strongly typed solution.

Comment: One thing to notice in this solution is that you should not declare the type variable as some typescript variable type.
For example (readonly type: string = ADD_BOOK;) will not work! (if we suppose that ADD_BOOK constant is defined as a string).

Answer (score 9):

Ok, it's very interesting topic. I missed new realese (4.0) but I updated libraries in my repo and I saw that I have the same problem.

That's right. Payload attribute was deleted from Action in new release. If are you use effects to dispatch action, solution is simple and can you read them in [migration note](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#ngrxstore)

but if you want dispatch to pass payload, you can create parametrizied Action in this way:

```
export interface ActionWithPayload<T> extends Action {
  payload: T;
}
```

so if you added this interface you can change reducer in this way:

```
export class SomeObject {
    company: string;
    site: string;
    department: string;
    line: string;
}

export function titleReducer(state = { company: 'MyCo', site: 'London' }, action: ActionWithPayload<SomeObject>): ITitle {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_TITLE':
            return {
                company: action.payload.company,
                site: action.payload.site,
                department: action.payload.department,
                line: action.payload.line
            }
            ...
```

It's the best walkaround, what I found. I must understand better the reason for this change, and if I will find better soulution I added them here

Comment: Awesome, thank you. What would this look like if I did use effects?

Comment: Im not sure I understand your question. Are you asking about how looks effect if you use ActionWithPayload?

Comment: I am asking about your comment "If are you use effects to dispatch action, solution is simple", I haven't understood what is going on in the before and after of the migration notes

Comment: so I wondered what the effects based solution might look like?

Answer (score 3):

Please made change in `app.module.ts`

```js
imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot({ appTutorial: TutorReducer } as ActionReducerMap<any,any>),
]
```

It can remove error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also found this approach to be helpful: to import the original `Action` interface with the `as` clause and extend it with a `payload` property.

In this case no changes to the rest of the code are necessary: https://blog.dmbcllc.com/upgrade-ngrx-4-x/.

Answer (score 0):

I was here with the same error message but with another cause:

on my builder I had something like:

```
.addCase(setFlight.type, (state, action) => {
  state.flight = action.payload
});
```

with the action like this:

```
const setFlight = createAction<Flight>('flight/set');
```

and then always got the error "payload does not exist on type action", the thing I should have done was to remove `type` in the first parametere of `.addCase()` , so the reducer should look like this:

```
.addCase(setFlight, (state, action) => {
  state.flight = action.payload
});
```

Now the `payload` is available in dropdown and error is gone.