# Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I use ngrx in my Angular app.

How to fix the error
**Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'never'.**

// auth.effects.ts

```
 effectLogInSuccess$ = createEffect(
    () =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(AuthActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS),
        tap((user) => {
          console.log(user);
          localStorage.setItem('token', user.payload.token);
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
        })
      ),
    { dispatch: false }
  );
```

// auth.actions.ts

```
export const actionLogInSuccess = createAction(
  AuthActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  props<{ payload: any }>()
);
```

[image]

Comment: pass `actionLogInSuccess`  instead of AuthActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS for example: `ofType(actionLogInSuccess)`

Comment: Can you check if the answers on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412448/property-payload-does-not-exist-on-type-action-when-upgrading-ngrx-store) helps or not?

Comment: inside `tap` you will not get input param as `user`, but you will get `action : LOGIN_SUCCESS`.

Comment: @AgilAtakishiyev I've already checked this post, thanks. Yes, it should work, but actually, I'm trying to rewrite this code with createAction. I think I need to export action types as a union somehow, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @navnath should I rewrite this part inside tap?

Comment: @Alexy thanks, it's fixed the issue, but I don't understand how. I thought I need to pass inside ofType the type of action, like this '[Auth] Login Success'

Comment: @Milena operator ofType must know what action type you are passing. When you pass a string, he cannot figure out what type of action you pass. You can provide type `ofType<V extends Action>`  or you can try the link solution above

Comment: @Alexy you're absolutely right, I found the explanation in official documentation [Incorporating State](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects#incorporating-state) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**: to pass authActions.actionLogInSuccess inside ofType operator

// auth.effects.ts

```
 effectLogInSuccess$ = createEffect(
    () =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(authActions.actionLogInSuccess),
        tap((action) => {
          console.log(action);
          localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
        })
      ),
    { dispatch: false }
  );
```

**Solution 2**: to provide a type for action parameter

// auth.effects.ts

```
 effectLogInSuccess$ = createEffect(
    () =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(AuthActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS),
        tap((action: any) => {
          console.log(action);
          localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
        })
      ),
    { dispatch: false }
  );
```